# Online Database WebApp / Service

Tags: javascript, dropbox

i'm experimenting by mounting a website hosted on my Dropbox Public folder. Files can my accesed and I used my domain name to redirect to de index.html public url.
I can run javascript, bootstrap, jquery and that stuff but not php (for obvious security reasons of dropbox). 
I would like to save data from the website. We all know that JScript is not allowed to write files or anything outsite the browser or the webpage itself.

I've been searching for a webapp/service that provides me a database or something like that let me save data from javascript. Somethingthat get connected to my host and gives me an API to the service or something like that.

Anyone heard about something like this? Or any other way I can get data saved? (serializing a JS object to a file would be just enought to me)

Comment: Honestly, wouldn't it be easier to just get a real web host?

Comment: of course it is but where would be the fun/challenge? :) just having fun with this

Comment: The fun/challenge would be in writing such API yourself. But to get back on track, I'm not aware of any such service.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From experience,

If you stick with trying to host something on Dropbox or anything that was not purpose meant for that, you will continually run into problems like this.

In the end spending (wasting) more time, energy and money on workarounds, rather than having fun in a real hosted environment (cloud based is more fun than DB!)

Do yourself a favor and move to a hosting platform, and spend that energy more wisely in creating a website or product (maybe that will make you money even)

There are plenty of free hosting platforms to get your started.

A quick serach on Google:

http://appfog.com/
https://pagodabox.com/